# Overriding $locationProvider.htmlMode for oAuth callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth

My angular.js app uses `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to enable SPA routing. However, there are places where I need to handle Google and Twitter oAuth callbacks (ie, physically route to /auth/twitter).

```
    $location.path('/auth/twitter');
    $location.replace();
```

However, I can't temporarily switch $locationProvider back to html5Mode(false) because $locationProvider cannot be injected into my controller (generates this error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$locationProviderProvider%20%3C-%20$locationProvider)

How do can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$window.location.href` instead.